# How to detect backup drive in windows using python?

Tags: python

I have 2 drives, OS drive and the backup drive in windows.

I want to write a python script that detects the backup drive and returns the letter it is assigned and makes sure it is an external disk not `thumbdrive` or `dvdrom`. The letter assigned to the drive can vary.

Is there a way to do that in python? I have been searching through but to no avail.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a way to do that. Whether a drive is used for "backup" or for "something else" depends entirely on the user's behavior, not in any property inherent to the drive itself. I think you'd have to *assume* something about the drive (e.g. a label, presence of an OS, or some other detail) to make your determination, but it wouldn't be reliable.

Comment: IMHO you have to iterate drives starting with `C` comparing each with `SystemDrive` environment variable value and drive type (`hdd`, `dvdrom`, `thumbdrive` etc). First found drive will be yours.

Comment: @lospejos OP wants a programmatic way to decide if a given drive is being used for "backup" purposes or not. How does what you propose address that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to detect the drive if its a external HDD using python.

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI()
for disk in c.Win32_LogicalDisk(["Caption", "VolumeName"], DriveType=3):

print disk
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment

> Is there a way to do that in python?

I think the short answer is: No. Not in Python, not in another language.

> I want to write a python script that detects the backup drive

I don't think there's a way to do this. There's nothing inherent to a drive that could be used to detect whether a connected drive is intended by the user to be a "backup" drive or for something else. In other words, whether a drive is a "backup" drive or not is determined by the user's behavior, not by the properties of the drive itself.

There're flags that can be set when a drive gets formatted (e.g. whether it's a bootable drive or not, etc), but that's about it.

If we're talking about a method that's intended for *your personal use only*, then something that might work is the following:

1. Create a naming convention for your drives (i.e. their labels when formatting), such as making sure your backup drives have the word "backup" somewhere in it;
2. Make sure you *never* deviate from this naming convention;
3. Write a program that will iterate over your drives looking for the word "backup" in their names (a simple regular expression would work).

Obviously, this would only work as long as the convention is followed. This is not a solution that you can arbitrarily apply in other situations where this *assumption* does not hold.

> makes sure it is an external disk not thumbdrive or dvdrom.

This one might be tricky. If you connect an external HDD into a USB plug, the system would know the drive's capacity and the fact that it's connected through the USB interface, but I think that's about it.